# VBA Run Macro Once a Day

Tags: vba, time, excel

I need some code to run a macro just once a day, it doesn't matter how many times you open the file where is the macro.

If the file is not opened one day it doesn't have to run the macro, just do it when it is opened.

It has to have a ¨internal" variable or something like that, I guess, that keeps the info whether the macro has alredy run or not this day.

Besides, to make it more difficult, I suppose, the macro open a different Workbook each day.

Any thoughts.

I am novice, so forgive me if that is so clear. Thanks in advance.

EDITED: I found some code [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/560086-how-run-macro-first-time-workbook-opened-date.html):

that seems to do it but you have to create an extra sheet, I would like to dont do that.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim rngFindTodaysDate As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Status")

        On Error GoTo X
        Set rngFindTodaysDate = .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Find(Date)
        If rngFindTodaysDate Is Nothing Then
            .Range("A" & .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = Date

            '''''  your Code  Here

        End If
    End With
    X:
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you expect your macro to do? If you need to run anything once a day, put a button, tell somebody to click on it once per day even they open the file 100 times... OMG it's not clear what you need sorry :(

Comment: I need that my macro runs just once a day, it doesn't matter how many times you open the file it just runs once per day. I can't tell the user to do it because it has to do it automatically. If you need more info just let me know

Comment: I would say you keep a value : e.g. 0 in a cell in this sheet. Then when macro is run, change that value to : e.g. 1. Then no matter how many times the sheet opens and macro gets invoked, sicne the cell valus is 1, the macro will exit and not complete the full process.

Comment: thanks, I have alredy thought about that, but I was thinking in something more "pro", something that doesn't involve a cell i a sheet, but anyway, I appreciete your time.

Comment: You can use a defined name to store the last-run date instead of putting it on a sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a (named) range, a single cell, in your workbook where the last time & date the macro is run is stored by the macro itself:

```
Sheetx.Range("rLastRun").Value2 = Now()
```

Add that to the end of your macro or at least **after** the following check, where your macro checks if the last time run cell value is before today. Then the total would look like:

```
If Sheetx.Range("rLastRun").Value2 < Date Then

    <your macro>

    Sheetx.Range("rLastRun").Value2 = Now()

End If
```

---

For the opening a different file each time you have to be more specific as with the information provided so far we cannot help there. Ask youself the following:

1. Is there any logic in the files properties?
2. Does it have the same name every time except for a timestamp (eg. *Input20121128.xls* and *Input20121127.xls*?
3. Is the document name in a limited pool of possible names?
4. Is it always in the same folder?
5. Does it have a specific creator, date, time, ...?

With information provided your file lookup would be:

```
Dim strInputfile As String

<other code>

strInputfile = "<standardfolderstring>" & Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy") & " Test.xlsx"
```

Comment: hi, yes, that is it. 1 --> the files have a logic names. 2--> just changes the date. 4 --> in the same folder always. The name would be something like "28/11/2012 Test.xlsx" and the date changes dialy. If I need to provide more info just let my know it. Thanks.

Comment: Added code at the bottom. If this answers you question please tick it so everyone knows you are helped out and need no further assistance with this issue. If not please specify this question further. If you have a new question then please start a new question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Windows Task Scheduler to automatically open the file once a day. There's a really good [step-by-step tutorial here](http://krgreenlee.blogspot.co.uk/2006/04/excel-running-excel-on-windows-task.html) with the required VB Script code included.

If the user may also be opening the file manually, you will want a state variable which records whether the macro has already run that day. The best bet is probably to have a sheet dedicated to recording this. Perhaps call it `RunTimes`. Then you can add the following line to your `Workbook_Open` event:

```
If Date > Application.Max(Sheets("RunRecords").Range("A:A")) Then
    Call YourMacroName
    Sheets("RunRecords").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Date
End If
```

Comment: I see  you're not keen on having an extra sheet. You could hide it, or if your macro changes something predictably every time it runs then you could use that as your condition in the If statement.

Comment: thanks, I think I am going to go for that solution, to hide the sheet, but I thought it would had a "internal variable" that keeps that kind of info without have to add extra data to a sheet or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the logic, please look into it.

Store a value : e.g. 0 in a cell in the sheet target to run the macro. Then when macro is triggered, change that value to : e.g. 1. Then no matter how many times the sheet opens and macro gets invoked, sicne the cell valus is 1, the macro will exit and not complete the full process

Comment: Thanks, but like I said I was looking for something that wouldn't involve a cell change, but anyway I appreciete your effort.

Comment: If you would keep a hidden sheet anyway :) it's worth doing it the most simplest/efficient way if that does the job. You can call the macro at Worksheet open event. However, when there're more options you should choose accordingly, I'll leave it up to you. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Personally I prefer the ideas that others have suggested to solve this... possibly using a single cell, filled with the current date and colour the date white to hide it... If not give this a try:

If you do not want to have a work sheet, you could use an external text file, in the same dir for example. When the XLS opens it will read the textfile to see the current date, then if it doesn't match today, run your once a day code and update the text file to today's date else do nothing.

```
Public txt_file_location As String
Public txt_file_name As String
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    txt_file_location = "C:\Documents and Settings\Chris\Desktop"
    txt_file_name = "test.txt"
    Dim dateToday As Date
    Dim dateInFile As Date
    dateToday = Date ' will be used for both comparison and for writing to txt file if need be
    dateInFile = txtfile_read(txt_file_location, txt_file_name)    ' On open - read the text file to check what the current date is.

    If (dateToday <> dateInFile) Then

        ' ok the date in the text file is different to today's date, so your script needs to be called here

        Call do_some_work ' a function that runs once a day...

        ' Now we need to update the textfile to todays date to prevent rerunning
        Call save_to_text_file(txt_file_location, txt_file_name, dateToday)
    Else
        MsgBox ("The script has already ran today")
    End If

End Sub
Sub do_some_work()

    ' here could be one of the functions that needs to run once a day
    MsgBox ("Some work was done!")

End Sub
Function txtfile_read(txt_file_dir, file_name)
    Dim iFileNumber As Long
    Dim strFilename As String
    strFilename = txt_file_dir & "\" + file_name
    iFileNumber = FreeFile()
    Open strFilename For Input As #iFileNumber
    Dim txt As Variant
    Do While Not EOF(iFileNumber)
        Line Input #iFileNumber, myLine
        txtfile_read = myLine
    Loop
    Close #iFileNumber
End Function
Function save_to_text_file(txt_file_dir, file_name, content_to_be_written)
    Dim iFileNumber As Long
    Dim strData As String
    Dim strFilename As String
    strFilename = txt_file_dir & "\" + file_name
    iFileNumber = FreeFile()
    Open strFilename For Output As #iFileNumber
    Print #iFileNumber, content_to_be_written
    Close #iFileNumber
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciete your time and effort. Regards

Comment: No worries - was a nice way to burn some time while the coffee was brewing! Happy coding :)